# Python - Cant call/skip a method

Tags: python, methods, skip

EDIT:

I will add the whole code, the names of clases and stuff are in spanish but i hope you understand:

```
class Rubro():
'''
Representa un rubro de venta. Por ejemplo: pastas y quesos son dos
rubros diferentes.
'''
def __init__(self, id, nombre, descripcion, icono=None):
    self.id = id
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.descripcion = descripcion
    self.icono = icono
    self.col_variedades = {}
    self.objBroker = persistencia.obtener_broker(self, None)

def obtener_todos(self):
    self.objBroker.cargar_todo() 

class Broker():
def cargar_todo(self):
    pass


class sqliteBrokerArticulos(Broker):

def __init__(self):
    self.obj_db = sqliteDB()

def cargar_todo(self):
    return self.ejecutar("SELECT * FROM articulos")

def ejecutar(self, sentenciaSQL):
    conn = self.obj_db.abrir_conexion()
    try:
        conn.execute(sentenciaSQL)
        conn.commit()
    except:
        return False
    self.obj_db.cerrar_conexion()
```

I dont know how to explain it really, this is the code:

```
class A():

    def a(self):
        return self.objC.b()

class B():
    def b(self):
       #do something

class C(B):

    def b(self):
       #do something else
```

The problem is that it does not get into b(), It just skip it, and goes out of a() when it reachs that line

I dont know what could it be.

Comment: Please specify, how you're calling any method here. There are only class definitions so far. Besides that, you missed the `object` for the baseclasses in all classes. Maybe that's already your problem.

Comment: You probably simplified too much. Even with the necessary additions to just make the code valid, I still see no way how `b` could not be called.

Comment: Another problem: you can't have an empty body after a `:`.  You need at least `pass` to make this code runnable.

Comment: Simplifying your code is good for SO questions, but it should run and show the problem at hand so we can understand the issue.

Comment: I edited the post with the actual code. 
Thanks for helping ^^

Comment: Is your actually code indented as you copied it here? Indentation *is* part of the syntax in Python. You have to get it exactly right...

Answer (score 0):

Are you wondering why the B.b() method is never called? Or why the C.b() method is never called?

If the former, it's because in C.b(), you don't call the superclass method:

```
>>> class B(object):
...   def b(self):
...     print "in B.b"
...
>>> class C(B):
...   def b(self):
...     print "in C.b"
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.b()
in C.b
>>> class C(B):
...   def b(self):
...     print "in C.b"
...     super(C, self).b()
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.b()
in C.b
in B.b
>>>
```